# Can't install Xamarin.iOS 11.14 from Windows 10 Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

At Visual Studio 2017 Pro on Windows 10,  when I try to connect my Mac, it wants Xamarin.iOS 11.14  but when I click INSTALL, it connects to Mac and gets up to about 88% and then:

"Xamarin.iOS versions mismatch
An error occurred while trying to download Xamarin.iOS'11.14'
There were problems installing Xamarin.iOS'11.14'. Please try again...

I first did:  File > New > Project > iPhone.. > Singe View App > Device Support iPad >

Restarted both computers, no effect.

Comment: Did you update your MAC as well. XAMARIN has to be updated on both platforms, not just he PC.

Comment: The failure occurs when VS on Windows is doing auto mac installation.  Presently, I'm attempting to manually install Xamarin at the Mac itself...

Comment: You have to make sure that the version of Xcode ,VS for Mac and VS for Window are up to date

Comment: Ah, hah! VS on Windows is 15.8.4. Upgrading to 15.8.5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Xamarin.iOS on the Mac itself.  Auto provisioning failed also, and I had to install that manually on the Mac.  But now I'm building and debugging from VS on Windows to my slave Mac.  Hear that iOS?  You're now a slave to my Windows.  :-D

Comment: where did you download just Xamarin.iOS 11.14?